# Ansible: set_fact on a json object

Tags: python, json, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a json object in an Ansible variable (`my_var`), which contains values similar to the following:

```
{
    "Enabled": "true"
    "SomeOtherVariable": "value"
}
```

I want to modify the value of `Enabled` in `my_var` and have tried the following:

```
set_fact:
  my_var.Enabled: false
```

and

```
set_fact:
  my_var['Enabled']: false
```

Which both give errors similar to:

> "The variable name 'my_var.Enabled' is not valid. Variables must start
>   with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters,
>   numbers and underscores."

Can this be done with set_fact or is there some other way of achieving this?

Comment: If you have a data structure in a variable, how does the way you created it matter?

Comment: It was a dictionary in JSON and it is a dictionary in Ansible. Could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this was my solution - probably not the most eloquent:

```
- set_fact:
    my_temp_enabled_var: '{ "Enabled": "false" }'

- set_fact:
    my_temp_enabled_var: "{{ my_temp_enabled_var | from_json }}"

- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ my_var | combine(my_temp_enabled_var) }}"
```

Comment: This can be shortened to a single task `my_var: '{{ my_var | combine({ "Enabled": false }) }}'`. You don't need to use `from_json`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new dictionary with a Jinja2 template:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_var:
      Enabled: true
      SomeOtherVariable: value
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var
    - set_fact:
        my_var: '{ "Enabled": false, "SomeOtherVariable": "{{ my_var.SomeOtherVariable }}" }'
    - debug:
        var: my_var
```

And the result:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "SomeOtherVariable": "value"
    }
}

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var": {
        "Enabled": false,
        "SomeOtherVariable": "value"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up going with the solution I posted. If the json wasn't passed in and could be created in the playbook as per your example, your solution would be ideal.

Comment: I beg to differ. If the object is passed in as a large serialized json object, then your approach is simply not feasible. It would require reconstructing the entire object in the task  to set one attribute. The example I gave of the json is a simplification of the actual object.

Comment: Except that it's the way to do it **especially** with what you call "*a large serialized JSON object*". Because, if it contained nested dictionaries your `combine` method would replace the whole branch, not only the leaf.

Comment: That is a good point. It was lucky that in this case that the leaf was on the top branch. It is a bit concerning that your approach is the only way to do it if it is a nested object several levels down.. Couldn't clones of each branch at each sub-level be made and combined iteratively to produce the same result?